# CSS Navigation bar animation

Tags: html, css, animation

i have just started my eportfolio and the first thing i have put is a navigation bar. Bare in mind i am by no means an expert at html or css and let me first say is i didnt make the original of this. The example was alot different which is why i have encountered a few problems when making it how i want it to be. Anyway here is the code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYpe html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css"/>
<title>ePortfolio</title>

</head>

<body>

<div class="Navigation">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="Navagation_Title">
            <a href="#">About me</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/3yiC6Yq.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="Navagation_Title">
            <a href="#">Games Fundementals</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/40Ly3VB.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="Navagation_Title">
            <a href="#">System Fundementals</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/00kih8g.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="Navagation_Title">
            <a href="#">Programming</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/2rT2vdx.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="Navagation_Title">
            <a href="#">Web Design</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="Navagation_Title">
            <a href="#">Extra</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="Navagation_Title">
            <a href="#">Extra</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="Navagation_Title">
            <a href="#">Extra</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="Navagation_Title">
            <a href="#">Extra</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="Navagation_Title">
            <a href="#">Extra</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="Navagation_Title">
            <a href="#">Extra</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="Navagation_Title">
            <a href="#">Extra</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="Navagation_Title">
            <a href="#">Extra</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/8k3N3EL.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is the CSS which is what is giving me problems

```
body {
background: #ccc; 
background-color: #E6E6E6
}

* {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
}

.Navigation {
width: 100%; height: 320px;
overflow: hidden;

margin: 100px auto;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 3);
}

.Navigation ul {
width: 100%;
}
.Navigation li {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 100px;
float: left;

border-left: 1px solid #888;

box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);


transition: all 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
}

.Navigation ul:hover li {width: 60px;}
.Navigation ul li:hover {width: 640px;}

.Navigation li img {
display: block;
}

.Navagation_Title {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
position: absolute;
left: 0; bottom: 0; 
width: 640px;   

}
.Navagation_Title a {
display: block;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 15px;
font-size: 16px;

}
```

Sorry about the lengh of this post but heres the problems its giving me. The width isnt correct. I would like to add an equation where the width of the pictures is 100% of the page divided by the amount of pages but im not sure where to do it. It also just seems abit buggy in genral. if you hover over the last page the animation will be glitchy. Im sure there is an easy fix, just playing around with the widths or something but i cant seem to get it. any help is appriciated

Comment: Do you want this equation when you `:hover` a img?

Comment: well both. if you are just looking at it, it should contian all the images without going off the page. and also if you hover over one

Answer (score 0):

The original seems to be set up to be used with a specific width (for `.Navigation`) and a specific amount of entries.
Using percentages for the navigation's width will almost always result in something glitchy.

To be able to safely add additional entries, you'll have to set the width back to the inital value `885px` and then add `61px` for each additional entry.

Example for two more entries:

```
.Navigation {
    width: 1007px;
}
```

To support 13 entries as in the code you provided, the width would have to be `1373px`.

Comment: Ok i tried it and it didnt work but i then did this calculation.
Width of image = 640px
total images = 13
so width of hovered image = 640px
width of un-hovered image = 40px 
so total container width = 640 + 40*12 = 1120px; (12 because there will be 12 tabs open + 1 image)
default width = 1120/13 = 86px;
*/

I did this and it works pretty nicely. thanks for the help anyway

Comment: You were not using the code provided in your qustion anymore then. Un-hovered images in there are 60px wide, plus 1px border.

Comment: yeh in the original it was 40 so i used that as a guide. but anything can be substituted in like i have 70px right now

Answer (score 0):

With this few lines you can calculate the width for each li:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var pics = $("li").size(); 
  var widthNav = $(window).width()/pics;
});
```

I hope this helps you a little bit :)

Comment: hey thanks for the help. this is my eportfolio for uni and the first draft can only use html and css. not even any javascript. i appriciate the help anyway though

Comment: Ok, is the number of pics static ?

Comment: which browser do you use?

Comment: i personally use chrome but i wanna make my eportfolio compatible for all of them

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with the Approach of Lucas is, that it doesn't take the custom size of the Website in account. So dependend on the Compatibility you want to give, you could use "calc" to get the exact size you want.

Here is the code i setup that even calculates the size if one element is hovered so the size of all the others will change:

```
.Navigation li {
    ...
    width: calc((100% / 13));
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    ...
}
.Navigation ul:hover li {
    width: calc((100% - 640px) / 12);
}
```

of course you need to adjust the amount of elements if you will add or remove some.

Here is a Fiddle where you can see how it now works. => https://jsfiddle.net/bjLsaLav/1/

Comment: for some reason this makes there be no animation. it just jumps instead of sliding. It also cuts off the last page, i think abit of adjusting of the width would fix that though

Comment: Which browser and version do you use? with Chrome and Firefox the animation is working fine for me. Also i can always see all 13 of them.